# array with image path (uri) and caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The best way to get into and array an image url and caption to that image. this work but seem not optimum...

```
var imgs = Array();
imgs[0] = Array("1","a");
imgs[1] = Array("2","b");
imgs[2] = Array("3","c");
```

javascript and jquery used, maybe there is a bettre semantic to write it down...
it work, but look ugly to me

Comment: More detail needed. Language used and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript have a literal syntax, if that's what you're asking..

```
var array = [["foo","bar"],["baz","quux"]]
```